# can $\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$ be simplified?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I was working on a probability theory problem and got the following probability as an answer :

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

can this sum be simplified to a nicer looking thing ?

Comment: $n! \sum _{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k!}\sum _{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{ (-1)^i}{i!}$ appears to give the sequence https://oeis.org/A155521 starting with $n=1$

Comment: I found another way of obtaining the sequence https://oeis.org/A155521 using Mathematica: $n! \sum _{k=2}^n \frac{\text{Subfactorial}[n-k]}{k! \,\Gamma (-k+n+1)}$. Subfactorial numbers can be found listed in https://oeis.org/A000166 (According to Mathematica, Subfactorial Numbers can be calculated using the incomplete Gamma Function thus: $\text{Subfactorial}[n-k]=\frac{1}{e}\Gamma (-k+n+1,-1)$). This is hardly a simplification though.

Answer (score 3):

One can reduce to a single summation. Let it be $a_n$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n x^n&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}
\\&=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}
\\&=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+k}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}
\\&=\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\right)
\\&=(e^x-1-x)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\sum_{n=j}^{\infty}x^n
\\&=\frac{e^x-1-x}{1-x}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^j}{j!}=\frac{1-(1+x)e^{-x}}{1-x},
\end{align*}
and $1-(1+x)e^{-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{k-1}{k!}x^k$ implies $\color{blue}{a_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{k-1}{k!}}$.

In terms of [subfactorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), $a_n=1-\dfrac{!n}{n!}-\dfrac{!(n-1)}{(n-1)!}$.

Comment: Excellent simplification. However I think there is a small typo in the last equation. I think it should be $$a_n=1-\left(\frac{!n}{n!}+\frac{ !(n-1)}{(n-1)!}\right)=1-\frac{!n+ n\, (!(n-1))}{n!}$$

Comment: @JamesArathoon: oops, you're right - let me edit your first formula in...

Comment: Using the recurrence relation $!n=n\, (!(n-1))+(-1)^n$ from the Wikipedia page on subfactorials, a further small simplification follows $$a_n=1-\frac{2(!n)-(-1)^n}{n!}$$